# access 2 list with relations

Tags: 2013, list

I have two list called `Employee` and `EmpInfo`

columns for list `Employee` Name and Designation

columns for list `EmployeeInfo` Name and Address

So 2 list are linked with column called `Name`

I get information from first list as below

```
 using (var site = new SPSite(spWebUrl))
        {
            var web = site.RootWeb;
            var list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Employee");
            listItems = GetListItemsAsList(list.Items);
        }



 private List<SPListItem> GetListItemsAsList(SPListItemCollection liCol)
    {
        List<SPListItem> toReturn = new List<SPListItem>();
        List<SPListItem> childList = new List<SPListItem>();
        foreach (SPListItem li in liCol)
        {
            toReturn.Add(li);
        }
        return toReturn;
    }
```

So inside method GetListItemsAsList i want to access 2nd list `EmployeeInfo`  and then add records to `toReturn`  list

How to do this?

**Update1**
I found way to search records of one list in other list but it adds record from second to returning list. For example if `Employee` list has 5 records and `EmployeeInfo` has 2 records. Then if both record matches from `EmployeeInfo` then it should return only 5 records with field from second list appended.

My below code adds 2 records so total count is 7 which is wrong.

```
 private List<SPListItem> GetListItemsAsList(SPListItemCollection liCol)
    {
        List<SPListItem> toReturn = new List<SPListItem>();

        foreach (SPListItem li in liCol)
        {
            string spWebUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;

            //Get the OrgChart list items
            using (var site = new SPSite(spWebUrl))
            {
                var web = site.RootWeb;
                var list = web.Lists.TryGetList("EmployeeInfo");
                SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Name'/>" + "<Value Type='Text'>" + li["Title"] + "</Value></Eq></Where>>";
                //query.Query = "<Where><And><Gt><FieldRef Name='ID'/>" + "<Value Type='Counter'>" + itemIndex + "</Value></Gt><Eq><FieldRef Name='Status'/>" + "<Value Type='Text'>Approved</Value></Eq></And></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='TRUE'></FieldRef></OrderBy>";
                SPListItemCollection items1 = null;
                items1 = list.GetItems(query);
                foreach (SPListItem li1 in items1)
                {
                    toReturn.Add(li1);
                }

            }



            toReturn.Add(li);
        }
        return toReturn;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
private List<Employee> GetListItemsAsList(SPListItemCollection liCol)
{
    List<Employee> toReturn = new List<Employee>();
    Employee tempEmp;

    foreach (SPListItem li in liCol)
    {
        string spWebUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;
        tempEmp = new Employee();
        tempEmp.Name = li["Title"].ToString();
        tempEmp.Designation = li["Designation"] != null ? li["Designation"].ToString() : string.Empty;

        //Get the OrgChart list items
        using (var site = new SPSite(spWebUrl))
        {
            var web = site.RootWeb;
            var list = web.Lists.TryGetList("EmployeeInfo");
            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
            query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Name'/>" + "<Value Type='Text'>" + li["Title"] + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

            SPListItemCollection items1 = list.GetItems(query);
            foreach (SPListItem li1 in items1)
            {
                tempEmp.Address = li["Address"] != null ? li["Address"].ToString() : string.Empty;
            }

        }
        toReturn.Add(tempEmp);
    }

    return toReturn;
}

public class Employee
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string Designation {get;set;}
   public string Address {get;set;}
}
```